# Why is a celery task not consumed by a worker that is free?

Tags: python, rabbitmq, celery

I have an application in Python with a microservices architecture and pipelines for which I use Celery along with RabbitMQ and Redis. In an application flow (machine learning training) 8 methodologies are needed, therefore a first worker called "Worker Training" sends 8 tasks to another worker called "Worker Training Model". This second one has 3 replicas to be able to finish the training faster. At first it works well, each worker consumes a methodology and processes it until finishing and consuming the next one.
However I am seeing that for example at this moment, 5 of the 8 tasks have already been completed, there are 2 workers (of the 3 replicas) processing a task, but there is 1 worker doing nothing! It should be processing the last missing methodology! Any idea why this happens? I think that in the end it will end up being processed in one of the other 2 workers when they finish with the one they have at the moment, but I need to be more efficient and not have workers doing nothing that can consume tasks.
My RabbitMQ dashboard looks like this right now:

[image]

(That task is the missing methodology and should be done by the free worker...)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is most likely caused by the prefetching. Read the [Prefetch Limits](https://docs.celeryq.dev/en/stable/userguide/optimizing.html#prefetch-limits) section, and the section after to find out how to make worker reserve as many tasks as they have (free) worker processes.

In short (TLDR):

```
task_acks_late = True
worker_prefetch_multiplier = 1
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, this will save me resources :)